# Swift_IoException in FileByteStream.php Unable to open file for reading

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to upload a csv file in php laravel
But i'm getting an error unable to open a file for reading.

Here is my mail code

```
 public function sendReports($to,$emailId,$filePath)
    {
        $this->recepient = $to;
        $data = [
            "emailId" => $emailId,
            "filePath" => $filePath
        ];
        Mail::send('emails.sendReports',$data, function($message) use ($filePath)
        {
            $message->from('$this->recepien');
            $message->to($this->recepient)->subject('PMS Forgot Password');
            $message->attach($filePath);
        });
    }
```